# Weird bad_access with dispatch_async

Tags: ios, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

I'm getting a really weird bad access error while using dispatch async. I managed to reduce it down to this segment of code in my program.

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    __block NSArray*foo = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        //Foo was initially declared here but then moved it outside.
        foo = [self someMethod];
        [foo retain]; // bad access here. Why ?
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),0) {
            // doesnt matter what happens here
    }); });
}

-(id)someMethod 
{
    return [self secondMethod];
}

-(id)secondMethod
{
    // was initially returning an autoreleased object from here. Changed it
    // to eliminate that as source of the error.
    id newThing = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    return newThing;
}
```

The code didnt initially look like this but this is how it is right now . Including allocating a dummy NSObject .

How is it possible for foo to get released in between calls inside a dispatch async ? I dont understand how this is possible. I know its difficult to suggest whats going from just this but any debugging suggestions would be helpful. I tried turning on NSZombies but I dont get any Zombies.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> How is it possible for `foo` to get released in between calls inside a `dispatch_async`?

It shouldn't, unless `someMethod` or `secondMethod` are, themselves, doing something asynchronously which might allow the autorelease pool to be drained in the interim.

> I tried turning on `NSZombies` but I dont get any Zombies.

If you've got zombies turned on and you're not getting a zombie, then I suspect the problem rests elsewhere. Frankly, I suspect that the root of the problem was eliminated in your process of simplifying the sample code for the purposes of the question:

A few other observations/clarifications:

1. You declared `foo` to be a `NSArray`, but then you're returning `NSObject`. I'll assume you meant it to be `NSObject` throughout.
2. You have a line of code that says:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),0) {
   ```

   I'll just assume that was a typo and that you intended:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   ```
3. The `foo` variable should definitely be inside the `dispatch_async` block. It doesn't really make sense to have a `__block` variable for something (a) you don't reference outside of that block for a block; and (b) for a block you're dispatching asynchronously.
4. The `secondMethod` should return an `autorelease` object, as you apparently originally had it. (Or you'd probably want to change `secondMethod` and `someMethod` to start with `new` in their names to avoid confusion and make life easier for yourself when you eventually move to ARC.)
5. If you `retain` the `foo` object, you'll want to also add the appropriate `release`. In fact, your original code sample returns a +1 object, and then retain it again, bumping it to +2, so you'd need two `release` calls.

Anyway, correcting for these various issues, I end up with the following, which does not generate an exception:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        NSObject *foo = [self someMethod];
        [foo retain]; // no bad access here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"foo = %@", foo);

            [foo release];
        });
    });
}

- (NSObject *)someMethod
{
    return [self secondMethod];
}

- (NSObject *)secondMethod
{
    return [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Furthermore, I would suggest, especially when using manual retain and release (MRR), that you run it through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the Xcode "Product" menu) and make sure you have a clean bill of health. (It would have pointed out some of the issues I mentioned.) It's not perfect, but it's remarkably good at identifying issues.

But, in short, the above code is fine, and if you're still getting an exception, update your question with working code that reproduces the exception.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Like I said this is a really weird issue.Sorry about the typos I screwed up while reproducing them from memory.  The code was like your corrected version initially without the [foo retain] which isnt really needed. When I then saw this bug I was totally stumped like I was seeing something that was impossible. I'm sure this is something stupid I've overlooked. I'll check it out and tell you what happened. In your knowledge is there any possible flow however unlikely by which [foo retain] would give bad access.

Comment: @eddardstark I'd suggest you update your question with a sample that can manifest the issue for us, and we'll help you figure it out. But I'd bet that in the process of writing and testing your simplified code, you'll find that the source of the exception rests elsewhere.